# Get a key/value object, where key is a value's enum

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB, how can I get a key/value object, where each key is an enum's value and value is the number of documents with the enum value.

In summary,

From

```
db={
  "orders": [
    { "_id": 1, "type": "news" },
    { "_id": 2, "type": "news" },
    { "_id": 3, "type": "news" },
    { "_id": 4, "type": "alert" },
    { "_id": 5, "type": "alert" }
  ]
}
```

How can I get this :

```
{
    news: 3,
    alert: 2 
}
```

I'm using an aggregation with group, like this :

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

And I get this :

```
[
  { "_id": 'alert', "count": 2 },
  { "_id": 'news', "count": 3 }
]
```

But from there, I don't know how to transform documents to have the expected result above.

Ty by advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregration like this will work:

```js
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group" : {
      "_id": null,
      "array": {  
        "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count"}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$array"}
    }
  }
])
```

The second `$group` stage contains an array of objects of the form `{ k: type, v: count }`. This is to make it consumable by the operator [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

The [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage then uses `$arrayToObject` to output the result in the desired format.

Comment: Hey, ty for your response :), works like a charm ! 
However, I have the impression that's a tricks, isn't it ?
But it works, so ty very much !